# ascending=True not working in django-mptt

Tags: django, django-mptt, django-packages

Hi good day I'm currently following Django-MPTT documentation and I have a problem using ascending=True. Here's my code:

views.py

```
def show_genres(request):
    Try01 = Genre.objects.filter(name="Rock")

    context = {'genres': Genre.objects.all(), 
                'sample_ancestor': Try01.get_ancestors(ascending=True, include_self=True)}
    return render(request, "sampletemp/startup.html", context)
```

when I'm using ascending=True an error occurs saying:

```
Exception Value: get_queryset_ancestors() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ascending'
```

How can I fix it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [See](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for instructions on how to post a MRE

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method

`models.get_ancestors` has an `ascending` field see [here](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/017c591c6ed2c43281ee2eba6b464c719578fc1d/mptt/models.py#L509)

`managers.TreeManager.get_queryset_ancestors` howerver has not,  as shown [here](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/017c591c6ed2c43281ee2eba6b464c719578fc1d/mptt/managers.py#L201)